# Subtracting same value from selected fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Looking to subtract the same value (512) from all rows with a primary key greater than 3599, in order to have the primary integer key be sequential.  Due to a botched import, the auto-increment, primary-key field has an unwanted gap of 512

The following code works perfectly to update every value, but it doesn't work for a selected range of values

```
UPDATE table
SET value = value - 512
```

How can the code be modified such that it only acts upon the rows with a value greater than 3599?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Works great!Normally wouldn't worry about the gap, except that having them sequential is very handy for selecting a random row, which is desirable for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET value = value - 512
WHERE VALUE > 3599
ORDER BY value;
```

You need to use `ORDER BY` to ensure that it won't create duplicate values while it's going. Without this, it might try to replace 5000 with 4488 before it replaces 4488 with 3976.

Comment: The order by only matters if the database is not properly isolating individual statements.

Comment: Apparently MySQL doesn't isolate statements. I just performed a test where I forced it to go in the wrong order, and it aborted with a duplicate key error.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't see any connection to isolating here. without the order by, you are depending on it doing the update in primary key order, which is not guaranteed in principle, though likely to be true at least currently in practice (for innodb, but not myisam). if you *increase* the ids or use myisam, you can absolutely get errors if you don't order by to avoid temporary duplicates. but that has nothing to do with other transactions or isolation at all.

Comment: @ysth I assumed he thought that the implicit transaction for a query would avoid checking for duplicates created temporarily within the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems.

First is the problem stated in the question: updated the existing keys. This is actually the easiest to solve:

```
UPDATE table
SET value = value - 512
WHERE value > 3599
```

But then we find the new problem: either new inserts are still going to pick up where they left off, and you've only shifted to the gap to later in the table, or you are using an unsafe mechanism to set the values, such as `MAX(value) + 1`. One of those two things must be true.

Finally, the last problem is either these keys are leaking to the end user in an inappropriate way or you are caring too much about whether there is a gap at all. In real databases, *gaps don't matter* and are a normal part of operating the system.